# Mobile UX testing

Tags: mobile, usability-testing

How effective is eye tracking for testing mobile UX? Are screen recorders good enough? We are in planning phase of a UX strategy for a new project so all inputs & suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Eye tracking and screen-recorders are two different things. What exactly is it you're looking to test? 'Mobile UX' as a whole isn't something you just test for, you need some criteria you're looking to measure against. (i.e. Ease of navigation / click-through rate / comprehension of the content...?)

Answer (score 0):

Several general things to consider for mobile UX:

- [How users hold the mobile device](http://katychuang.tumblr.com/post/46166645310)
- [Data input/output format](http://katychuang.tumblr.com/post/46174545824)
- [Device Screen Size](http://katychuang.tumblr.com/post/49014835266)
- [Gestures and motions](http://katychuang.tumblr.com/post/37792373049)

[Eye tracking has been done for ipad usage](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbEuAFLAwHw) before. Seems like it can be an [expensive](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/a-brief-history-of-eye-tracking/) and [finicky](http://sarahbrearley.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/my-first-experiences-with-the-tobii-mobile-eyetracking-kit/) way to go about collecting data because of the equipment required, but also very detailed data.

Comment: My first-hand experience with the eyetracking hardware mentioned in the post you suggested was that although it lost tracking a few times, it's extremely valuable and useful. If the budget is there, I'd say it is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Eye tracking would be tricky to measure when the screen is so physically small.

I think with a smart phone I'd more interested in the 'clicks' and how people use their fingers to navigate an app. Fingers are so imprecise when compared to mice and this often overlooked by advice on responsive design.

If you are going to film users you might actually be better stepping the camera back a bit so you can actually record the interaction including the hands holding and interacting with the device.

Answer (score 0):

WHen you say "are screen recorders good enough", do you mean is recording the screen sufficient, or should eye tracking be used on top of it? If so, then I would say that screen recording is sufficient, as long as you are clear about what you are looking for from the users. From what I've seen, one of the tricky parts of screen recording is watching gestures, since subtle movements such as taps and swipes can be lost or misinterpreted as non-touch gestures.

Of course, eye tracking isn't going to help you identify gestures ;)